# No Internet with self hosted Wireguard VPN on raspberry pi behind the router

Tags: vpn, troubleshooting, openwrt, wireguard

I'm self-hosting a Wireguard VPN in LAN connected raspberry pi. I used [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtUl7BfCNMY) to set it up and worked perfectly in a TP-Link router (TL-WR841N). I had to change the TP-Link router and have now an OpenWRT (in a MI 4A box).
I haven't changed anything but the router. I have added the applicable forwarding ports in the router. I can connect to the VPN (as I used to), and I can also SSH the raspberry pi from outside the LAN. But can’t browse the Internet. I think it must be an easy fix in the router configuration of which I’m unaware. Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot showing successful connection to the raspberry hosted WG VPN:

[![Screenshot showing successful connection to the raspberry hosted WG VPN][1]][1]

My `/etc/config/firewall` looks as follows (port forward configuration in the last two entries)

```
config defaults
    option syn_flood '1'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'

config zone
    option name 'lan'
    list network 'lan'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'ACCEPT'

config zone
    option name 'wan'
    list network 'wan'
    list network 'wan6'
    option input 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'

config forwarding
    option src 'lan'
    option dest 'wan'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCP-Renew'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '68'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option family 'ipv4'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-Ping'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option icmp_type 'echo-request'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-IGMP'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'igmp'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCPv6'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '546'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-MLD'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
    list icmp_type '130/0'
    list icmp_type '131/0'
    list icmp_type '132/0'
    list icmp_type '143/0'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Input'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    list icmp_type 'router-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'router-advertisement'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-advertisement'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Forward'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest '*'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-IPSec-ESP'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option proto 'esp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ISAKMP'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option dest_port '500'
    option proto 'udp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config redirect
    option target 'DNAT'
    option name 'Raspberry VPN'
    list proto 'udp'
    option src 'wan'
    option src_dport '51820'
    option dest_ip '192.168.1.9'
    option dest_port '51820'

config redirect
    option dest 'lan'
    option target 'DNAT'
    option name 'Raspberry SSH'
    list proto 'tcp'
    option src 'wan'
    option src_dport '22'
    option dest_ip '192.168.1.9'
    option dest_port '22'
```

Comment: Does your LAN's main router have a route to your VPN network?

Comment: I'm unsure if I understand your question correctly. Wireguard is configured on the Raspberry Pi (Static IP 192.168.1.9) which is part of the LAN managed by the main router (IP: 192.168.1.1) which is connected via the WAN port to the box provided by the ISP. The router has a port forward for incoming VPN connections to the internal port in the Pi. I assume this is set correctly, as I can establish the connection (although I can't browse the Internet). External SSH connection to the Pi works well.

Comment: Right, but all that aside, does the router know where the 10.7.0.0/24 network is? Does it have a route to this subnet? Or does the Pi have NAT (iptables masquerade) enabled for the VPN clients?

Comment: Thanks @u1686_grawity !! you have pointed me into the right direction. I had to update one of the NAT rules that was indeed set in the Pi. I used an automated script when I first set the system so I was unaware of what it did actually do. After updating it works as before. I have updated the post with the solution. Thanks again! greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
Sincere thanks to u1686_grawity, who has pointed me in the right direction. The problem was that by changing router, I had also changed the LAN IPs to 192.168.1.0/255 (previously was 192.168.0.0/255); and the Pi's static IP to 192.168.1.9 (previously was 192.168.0.109). By checking the NAT table rules as suggested by @u1686_grawity, I've realized I had to change the POSTROUTING rule (see below):

```
iptables -t nat -n -L

Output:
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  10.7.0.0/24         !10.7.0.0/24          to:192.168.0.109  #Needs to be updated to 192.168.1.9
```

Just in case this helps someone:

In this particular case Wireguard was installed using the automatic installer [wireguard-install.sh](https://github.com/Nyr/wireguard-install) which uses the public IP address to determine the endpoint and routing settings in the configuration file. The script creates then a systemd service (wg-iptables.service) that applies the necessary rules every time the system boots. The service is created under /etc/systemd/system/, and it is enabled to run at startup using the 'systemctl enable --now wg-iptables.service' command.

In case the IP of the Wireguard server changes, you may choose to use the automatic installer to uninstall and then reinstall again, or (as I ended doing) modify the file *wg-iptables.service* accordingly. If you do the latter remember to reload the systemd manager configuration with the command 'systemctl daemon-reload'.